# What is [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly")]? A statement, directive, ...?

Tags: c#, attributes, assemblies, terminology

Sorry about the vocabulary question but I can't find this anywhere: how do you call this below?

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly")]
```

Is it a statement, a directive, ... ? I want to indicate that you have to insert that line in order to give `MyAssembly` access to your assembly's `internal` members, but I'd like to use a more specific term than "line".

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# language spec refers to it as an Attribute Specification (section 17.2).

> Attribute specification is the application of a previously defined attribute to a declaration. An attribute is a piece of additional declarative information that is specified for a declaration. Attributes can be specified at global scope (to specify attributes on the containing assembly or module) ...

Answer (score 7):

It's a [**Global Attribute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/284c1c4s(VS.90).aspx) applied at the [assembly level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

Comment: Great answer, +1, but I chose Jared's answer because `InternalsVisibleTo` is an attribute, but `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(“MyAssembly”)]` is an attribute *specification*. Ah, vocabulary! Thanks for your answer, I'm adding this info to my text :)